# Is it possible to display all submatrices each represented by a variable in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, submatrix

Is there any inbuilt function to display all the submatrices from a matrix in matlab? 
For displaying one submatrix we have the function x(:,m:n).
For eg: Consider a  4 x 4 matrix

```
   A = 14    11    16    16
       15     2    16     8
        3     5     3    13
       15     9    16     3
```

If the size of all submatrices is 1 x 2 , how to display all the submatices present in A? Also how to represent each submatrix with a variable (for eg; a1,a2..etc)

```
   a{1}=[14 11]
   a{2}=[16 16]
   .
   .
   a{8}=[16 3]
```

How to display all the submatrices in the form of a cell array? please help. thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use names like `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, etc. They are very hard to work with later! Try using a cell array: `a{1}=[14 11]`, `a{2}=[16 16]`, it will be much easier!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the mat2cell command to split the original matrix as desired, and then cell2mat to obtain the result as a (sub)matrix again. In your particular example, using the same matix A as above, you could use it this way:

```
B = mat2cell(A,[1 1 1 1],[2 2])

cell2mat(B(1,1))
ans =

   14   11

cell2mat(B(1,2))
ans =

   16   16

cell2mat(B(4,2))
ans =

   16    3
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Reshape the matrix into a linear array
2. Reshape the linear array into whatever format you want, which in this case is 2 by `x` matrix, so that each row is one sub-matrix.

   ```
   reshape(reshape(A', numel(A), 1), 2, numel(A)/2)'
   ```

If you want to cast the results into cells, you can use the command `mat2cell()`.

Comment: This works, but some explanation on how this works, rather than simply code dumping may be beneficial.  Also, the OP wants a cell array.  This only produces a 2D matrix.